# Matlab reading text issue

Tags: matlab, io

I'm trying to read a kind of structured text file into MatLab. It reads like this:

```
 Header

 Result  Damage  "Load Analysis"      0.002000000    Vector    OnNodes
ComponentNames "DN", "DT"
Values
    1  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    2  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    3  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    4  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
End Values

 Result  Damage  "Load Analysis"      0.004000000    Vector    OnNodes
ComponentNames "DN", "DT"
Values
    1  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    2  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    3  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
    4  0.00000000E+00  0.00000000E+00
End Values
```

And the values go on repeating themselves in blocks. I need to read only those 3 values from the lines within the repeating blocks for every block that is within the file. I thought about a code like this:

```
fid=fopen('FileName.res');
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ischar(strtrim(tline)) == 1
        continue
    else
    %command to put the values within a matrix of kind A[inf,3]
    end
end
```

The first issue is that when it comes to the lines that are actually numbers the command *ischar* returns *1* as value. This way I still couldn't get to the second part of putting the numbers into a matrix. Any ideas regarding these issues?

Comment: The output of `fgetl` is always going to be a character array unless the line only contains a newline character. One suggestion is to adjust your logic instead to look for 'Values' and read until you see 'End Values'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files have a consistent formatting I would look at [`textscan`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) as it is quite flexible and good for files with blocks like yours.

Otherwise, for a solution as close to your original code as possible, just try to read each line as a number, if it succed, add the number to your table, if it fails, go on to the next line.

```
fid=fopen('FileName.res');
fullTable = [] ;
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    tempRow = sscanf( tline , '%d%f%f' ).' ; %' // try to read the string as numbers
    if ~isempty(tempRow)
        fullTable = [ fullTable ; tempRow ] ; % // append numbers to the master table
    end
end
fclose(fid)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `fgetl` just reads in the whole line as a string.  i.e. `ischar('1 2 3')` returns true.  It might contain numbers, but the variable type itself is a string.  So you need to look not at the type returned by `fgetl`, but the content.

Untested but I think this will work:

```
fid=fopen('FileName.res');
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if strcmp(tline,'Values')
       tline = fgetl(fid); % this should read the line starting 1
       while strncmp(tline,'End',3) %only match first three letters
         % put values in matrix
         tline = fgetl(fid); % get next line
       end
    end
end
```

What this ought to do:

1) Read lines until it finds one that reads 'Values' (you may have to play with `strcmp`/`strncmp` if that whitespace is also read in).
2) Read the next line
3) Put values in matrix
4) Read the next line
5) If next line does not start 'End', go back to 3.
6) If next line does start 'End', go back to 1.